# In a certain game, $30$ balls of $k$ different colors are kept inside a sealed box. You are told only the value of $k$, but not the number of balls of

Tags: combinatorics

In a certain game, $30$ balls of $k$ different colors are kept inside a sealed box. You are told only the value of $k$, but not the number of balls of each color . Based on this, you have to guess whether is it possible to split the balls into $10$ groups of $3$ each, such that in each group the three balls  are of different colors.  Your answer is to be simple $YES $ or $NO$ . You win or loose a point according as your guess is correct or not. For what values of $k$ you can say $NO$  and be sure of winning ? For what values of $k$ , you can say $YES$ and be sure of winning? Justify your solution .

I can only make out that if $k=2$ then PHP(Pigeon hole Principle) we can say $NO$ . The argument is still trivial for $k=1$. Now, I am not getting how can we be obvious about saying $YES$ . Will there be a rigorous proof for the same ? Are the only possible choices for saying $NO$ is for $k=1,2$. If so, then is my way of saying $NO $ can be considered a valid solution? If not, then what are the other values of $k$? I am not quite getting it. There may be similar posts concerning the same topic on this site but I can't seem to find it either...

Comment: Well, if nothing else, consider this: what can you say, with certainty, if $k=30$? What if $k=29$? And when does that pattern stop?

Comment: @EricSnyder if $k=30$ , we can say the balls are each of $30$ different colors but $k$ can never be greater than $30$ as  we cannot have $30$ balls of $31$ different colors. So, if $k=30$ we will be sure about saying $YES$  . If $k=29$ , $2$ balls have same color. Then , if one put the two same color balls in the group of length $3$ , the answer can be $NO$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for any combination of $3n$ balls, it is possible to split them into $n$ groups of $3$ each with all balls in every group having different colors iff no particular color has more than $n$ balls.

"Only if" direction: if one color has more than $n$ balls, then at least one group will have at least two balls of this color.

"If" direction: prove by induction.

If $n = 1$, then we have $3$ balls, and every color has at most $1$ ball, so we can put them all in one group.

Assume we can group any combination of $3n$ balls in which no color has more than $n$ balls. Assume we have a combination of $3(n+1)$ balls such that no color has more than $n+1$  balls. Also, at most $3$ colors have more than $n$ balls (because otherwise there would already be more than $3n+3$ balls only in these colors). So, we can choose $3$ colors with the most balls, put one ball from each of them in the first group, and get a new combination of $3n$ balls, where no color has at most $n$ balls - which can be splitted into groups by induction assumption.

So, the question is equivalent to follow: for which $k$ we can guarantee that there will be a color that has at least $11$ balls, and for which $k$ we can guarantee there will be no such color.

It's clear we can guarantee there will be such color for $k = 2$, but can't for $k = 3$ (take $10$ balls of each color).

We also can guarantee there will not be such color with $k \geq 21$ (if one color has at least $11$ balls, then the rest $20$ colors have at most $19$ balls together, which is impossible), but can't gurantee with $k = 20$ (take one color with $11$ balls, and rest $19$ colors with one ball each).

So, for $k \leq 2$ we can say "NO", for $k \geq 21$ we can say "YES", and for all other we can't say anything.

Comment: If $k\geq 21$ , then we can say $YES$ but can we always  say $YES$  for  $k\geq 21$?...

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the difference. For any combination of balls with at least $21$ colors we can group the balls.

Comment: But I don't get the  if $n>1$ what u mean by "put three most common colors in a group , and get the same situation with less balls."...I dont get the case when $n>1$...How did u prove it for $n>1$?...

Comment: Wrote more detailed proof.